# How can you modify a formik input value after the user pastes in it?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik

I have a field where users will copy-paste in html links. Unfortunately a lot of companies will add additional text when using the "copy link" share feature, so the clipboard data is something like `take a look at this! www.blah.com`. I'm trying to strip out the extra text, and just update the input with the url.

To do this, I'm leveraging the `onPaste` handler from react. If I debug the handler and step through it slowly, it kinda works. The value gets updated to just the url, but the form is invalid. In real time, the `onPaste` handler seems to have no effect, so I think there's some timing issues. I've tried `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()` and neither helped.

Here's the formik input:

```
      <Field
        type="text"
        name={name}
        onPaste={onPaste}
      />
```

Here's the `onPaste` handler:

```
  const onPasteHandler = async (e: ClipboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (e.clipboardData) {
      let value = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
      const results = value.match(/(?:(?:https?:\/\/)|(?:www\.))[^\s]+/g);
      // update the value to the first result. If none, do nothing
      if (results && results.length > 0) {
        const target = e.target as HTMLInputElement;
        target.value = results[0];
        await formRef?.current?.validateForm();
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution. Formik has a function, `setFieldValue`, that helps. I ended up needing to use `e.preventDefault()` at the end of the function.

```
  const getPasteHandler = (setFieldValue: (field: string, value: any, shouldValidate?: boolean | undefined) => void) => {
    return (e: ClipboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      if (e.clipboardData) {
        let value = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
        const results = value.match(/(?:(?:https?:\/\/)|(?:www\.))[^\s]+/g);
        // update the value to the first result. If none, do nothing
        if (results && results.length > 0) {
          const target = e.target as HTMLInputElement;
          target.value = results[0];

          setFieldValue('link', results[0], true);
          e.preventDefault();
        }
      }
    }
  }

return (
 <Formik>
      {({ setFieldValue }) => (
        <Form>
          <TextInput
            name="link"
            onPaste={getPasteHandler(setFieldValue)}
             />
```

lots omitted for brevity there ^